# Как отобразить таблицу в html с помощью flask

Tags: python, flask, for

Ребята подскажите, только начал изучать flask, создал на питоне таблицу умножения и не могу её вывести на экран через html документ
Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def tabl_umn():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            print(i, '*', j, '=', i * j, end='\t')
        print()

@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('base.html', title='Главная страница', tabl_umn=tabl_umn())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            {{ title }}
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ tabl_umn }}</h3>     
    {% endblock %} 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ваша функция `tabl_umn` ничего не возвращает (где return?)

Comment: return же только одну итерацию выведет?

Comment: так запиши итерацию в переменную (объект), в список, и верни результат.

Comment: так и сделал, вопрос закрыт)